# Can a player swap position with a dead body in lifeboat?

Tags: lifeboat

In the [lifeboat](http://siadek.com/lifeboat.html) game the rules when you are unconscious specify that :

> Other players could swap their position with yours or steal your cards
>   and you can't defend yourself.

But nothing is specified for the cases where you are dead and still in the boat. There is a note allowing other players to steal your cards but nothing about position swapping.

Following the rules it seem to be disallowed (as it isn't specifically allowed), but does anyone have experience with either variant? Is there a FAQ with this info somewhere? The [official FAQ](http://www.gorillaboardgames.com/files/Lifeboatfaq.pdf) is really short and the extensions don't add any details about this.

Answer (score 7):

The FAQ you linked to I believe covers this. Since fights are started by a character refusing a seat exchange, a dead person's seat is just taken from them.

> **How do I start a fight?**
>
> Fights can only be started by a character refusing a mugging **or a seat exchange**. Incapacitated characters (unconscious **or dead**) cannot start a fight, join a fight or have a fight fought on their behalf. If somebody wants to take something from them, it just happens.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quote from the [rules](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/26777/lifeboat-rules-pdf):

> Unconciousness:
>
> People can take from you or trade places as normal but you cannot fight back.

I agree it's not stated in the section "death", but I see no reason why it shouldn't be the same.

Comment: Dead people are not conscious, so I wonder if that is sufficient.